# How can I use Application Settings in a mono project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mono, application-settings

I'm trying to port an application to Mono, however Mono doesn't support "Application Settings". I don't and won't use Mono Develop, the development is done with Visual Studio.

Is there any quick way to solve this? Or should I implement my own settings replacement class?

If it matters this is a VB.NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate on "Application Settings"?  Are you trying to use an app.config file?  Or maybe the settings tab of the project file?

Mono should support both of those.

Perhaps you could also elaborate on "doesn't support".  Are you getting an error message?  If so, what is the message?

Comment: Please see my more detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

The best place to ask questions like this is Mono dev mail list at http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-list

I'm sure that there is a workaround and there is no reason to implement it by-hand

And probably, the main reason of your issue is VB.BET because it's implementation on Mono is very backward in comparison with C#

Comment: This seems like a perfectly fine place to ask the question and not a very helpful answer. For me, I'm interested but not interested in following numerous places for things that interest me.

Answer (score 1):

Mono does not support this feature natively.  You many contribute to the code base immensely by implementing this feature for perhaps monodevelop, the VS style IDE for Linux and mono development in C# and other languages.

Answer (score 0):

@jpobst

see the following code from my application:

```
Dim Threshold As Integer = My.Settings.Threshold
```

And

```
My.Settings.Threshold = 15
```

These should be synced with Application / User Settings. Yes I'm using Visual Studio's Settings feature and app.config with "user" and "application" scope.

Mono doesn't support it. It's not implemented and *AFAIK always return nothing*. MoMA says it's [Monotodo](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA_-_Issue_Descriptions).